# How can I delete a maintenance plan with T SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 87 servers that each have maintenance plans that need to be deleted to be replaced with agent jobs.  Here's what I've tried:

```
DECLARE @planId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

select @planId = p.id
from msdb..sysmaintplan_plans p
where  p.name LIKE 'Night%';
PRINT @planId;
EXEC msdb..sp_delete_maintenance_plan  @planId;
```

and the result that I get:

> E0BC518C-CFD4-4BB0-A843-74B61B22B72E
>
> Msg 14262, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_delete_maintenance_plan,
>   Line 12 [Batch Start Line 3] The specified @plan_id
>   ('E0BC518C-CFD4-4BB0-A843-74B61B22B72E') does not exist.

How can I get this to work?  Would a powershell script work better?

Comment: That procedure has been deprecated for a long time now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-maintenance-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: So, is there a newer method?  Can this not be done via a script at all?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to look at [`sp_delete_job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and it's friends.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by this:

```
declare @folder_id uniqueidentifier
declare @plan_id uniqueidentifier
declare @plan_name nvarchar (100) = 'Plan Name'
select  @plan_id = id from msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_plans where [name] = @plan_name
select @folder_id = folderid from msdb.dbo.sysssispackages where name = @plan_name

exec msdb.[dbo].sp_ssis_deletepackage @plan_name,@folder_id
exec msdb.[dbo].[sp_maintplan_delete_plan] @plan_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides sp_delete_job, you may also want to have a look at sp_ssis_deletepackage, but this one is not documented. Try using Profiler to see what is called when you delete a maintenance plan.